# Diagonal calculation in a 3D square

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles, 3d

I have the information as shown in the following image: 
[image] i.e.: all sides (AB, BC CD and DA) and one diagonal (BD) and the height difference between the point A and the points B/C/D (855.35mm).

How do I calculate the length of diagonal AC (red line)?

Comment: That’s not really a “square,” now, is it? The figure isn’t even planar. You do have a triangular “base,” though, so try starting by working out the relative coordinates of those three points.

Comment: There are two possible locations for $A$ that have different distances from $C$, so you need some other criteria for choosing the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a square but a tetrahedron with base $BCD$ and height $h = 855.35$.

Label the edge lengths as
$$\begin{cases}
b   &= |CD| =  2578,\\
c   &= |BD| =  2828,\\
d   &= |BC| =  2128,\\
b_1 &= |AB| =  2060,\\
c_1 &= |AC|\\
d_1 &= |AD| =  2045\\
\end{cases}$$

$c_1$ will be the length we seek.

You can compute the volume of this tetrahedron in two different manners.

- $V = \frac13 \mathcal{A} h$ where $\mathcal{A}$ is area of $\triangle BCD$. 
  You can use [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron's_formula) to get $\mathcal{A}$.
  $$16\mathcal{A}^2 = (b+c+d)(-b+c+d)(b-c+d)(b+c-d)$$
- You can also compute the volume using [Cayley Menger determinant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cayley-MengerDeterminant.html).

$$288V^2 = \left|\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & b_1^2 & c_1^2 & d_1^2\\
1 & b_1^2 & 0 & d^2 & c^2\\
1 & c_1^2 & d^2 & 0 & b^2\\
1 & d_1^2 & c^2 & b^2 & 0
\end{matrix}\right|$$

Expanding the CM determinant and combine it with first result, one obtain following equation which is quadratic in $c_1^2$:

$$\begin{align}
16\mathcal{A}^2h^2 = 144V^2 
=& \phantom{+}\; b^2 b_1^2(-b^2-b_1^2 + c^2 + \color{red}{c_1^2} + d^2 + d_1^2)\\
 & + c^2 \color{red}{c_1^2}(\;b^2+b_1^2 - c^2 - \color{red}{c_1^2} + d^2 + d_1^2)\\
 & + d^2 d_1^2(\;b^2+b_1^2 + c^2 + \color{red}{c_1^2} - d^2 - d_1^2)\\
 & - (b^2c^2d^2 + b^2 \color{red}{c_1^2} d_1^2 + b_1^2 c^2 d_1^2 + b_1^2\color{red}{c_1^2} d^2)
\end{align}$$

With help of a CAS, we can substitute back the numerical values of $b,c,d,b_1,d_1$ into above equation and simplify. The end result is

$$\begin{align}c_1 
&= \sqrt{\frac{116153047144695\pm\sqrt{8168336037304042557755678133}}{19993960}}\\
&\approx 1135.385089196282 \;\text{ or }\; 3213.987289241557
\end{align}
$$
There are two possible solutions for $c_1$. The '+' solution corresponds to the
case where the [dihedral angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_angle) between the planes holding $\triangle ABD$ and $\triangle BCD$ is obtuse ( $> 90^\circ$). For the '-' solution, the dihedral angle is acute ($< 90^\circ$).

Judging from your picture, the dihedral angle at edge $BD$ is obtuse. The length you seek is the one $\approx 3213.987289241557$.

Comment: I am trying to create an excel spreadsheet to calculate c1, but I am not sure how to get the quadratic equation from the 5x5 matrix. Is this even possible in a excel? Perhaps I should just use the quadratic equation for c1, but again I don't know what it is. Could you expand on that please?

Comment: Thank you for elaborating on this, but I'll be honest. I unfortunately still can't figure out how to simplify this equation, because as far as I know excel cannot multiply numbers with letters i.e.: 15*c will not become 15c. Therefore if I substitute the numbers back into this equation, then it will not work as I have c1 as unknown, so it gives me an error. Apologies for being too much of a newbie...

Comment: @A.Bawor You can always use the Goal seek feature in Excel. (I'm using Excel 2007, it is accessible through the menu `Data` -> `Data tools` -> `What-if analysis`)

1. Setup 7 cells for the values of $b,c,d,b_1,c_1,d_1,h$ (put a guess value to $c_1$).
2. Place the entries of CM matrix in $5 \times 5$ cells.
3. Select the $5 \times 5$ cells, right click to name the range as `CM`
4. create a cell and use the function `=MDETERM(CM)` to compute the determinant of the named range CM.
5. create another cell which compute the difference of this determinant with $32\mathcal{A}^2 h^2$.

Comment: 6. Use the Goal seek feature to find the $c_1$ value which make the cell in step 5 goes to zero.

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your help! Works like a charm ;)

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the fact that A = (?, ?, 855.35), I think the figure is a tetrahedron instead of a square. It has BCD as the base and AA’ (= 855.35) as its vertical height. Therefore, all arrow-marked angles shown are $90^0$. Also, AC is a slant edge instead of a diagonal.

[image]

Apply Pythagoras to [$\triangle ABA’$ with AB and AA’ known] to get BA’.

Similarly, DA’ can be found from $\triangle ADA'$.

Apply Cosine law to [$\triangle BDC$ with all 3 sides known] to get $\angle BDC$.

Similarly, apply Cosine law to [$\triangle BDA’$ with all 3 sides known] to get $\angle BDA’$.

$\angle A’DC = \angle BDC - \angle BDA’$

Then, apply Cosine law [$\triangle A’DC$ with DA’, DC and $\angle A’DC$ known to get A’C.

Finally, apply Pythagoras to [$\triangle AA’C$] to get AC.